# Regarding code extract from Apple's WWDC 2017 Session 506 - Where is exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation() defined?

Tags: ios, swift, wwdc, apple-vision

In the WWDC 2017 video from session 506. There's a piece of the code in the 1st demo that looks like this:

```
let exifOrientation = self.exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()
```

The use of self. indicates that it is supposed to be a property from the ViewController. Given that this **exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()** method doesn't exist in a UIViewController class, I suppose ViewController is conforming to a protocol that grants that functionality. Can someone indicate which protocol that is?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you take a look at https://github.com/yulingtianxia/Core-ML-Sample/blob/master/CoreMLSample/ViewController.swift which is part of the [Core-ML-Sample](https://github.com/yulingtianxia/Core-ML-Sample) project on GitHub.

```
var exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation: Int32 {
    let exifOrientation: DeviceOrientation
    enum DeviceOrientation: Int32 {
        case top0ColLeft = 1
        case top0ColRight = 2
        case bottom0ColRight = 3
        case bottom0ColLeft = 4
        case left0ColTop = 5
        case right0ColTop = 6
        case right0ColBottom = 7
        case left0ColBottom = 8
    }
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        exifOrientation = .left0ColBottom
    case .landscapeLeft:
        exifOrientation = .top0ColLeft
    case .landscapeRight:
        exifOrientation = .bottom0ColRight
    default:
        exifOrientation = .right0ColTop
    }
    return exifOrientation.rawValue
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I am working on object localization and I think this Exif related method for grabbing the orientation may be wrong. One should follow WWDC sample code from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/training_a_create_ml_model_to_classify_flowers. I used the method in this project and things worked as expected.

Comment: Further, I am on iOS 12.0 and apple's own demo source code should be trusted more than GitHub from someone else, holding all else equal

Comment: @kawingkelvin exifOrientation is the implementer's own variable definition; the actual values are defined here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation

Answer (score 0):

It's worse than that. It refers to a function that is in their app's subclass of UIViewController().  I could not find a copy of this app anywhere in the WWDC samples -- I don't think that they included it.

But, this project seems to have an equivalent:

https://github.com/yulingtianxia/Core-ML-Sample/blob/master/CoreMLSample/ViewController.swift#L107

Comment: Thanks, Lou! I'll take a look at this GitHub page and see what I can learn from it. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to this code [posted here](https://github.com/yulingtianxia/Core-ML-Sample/blob/master/CoreMLSample/ViewController.swift):

They create the variable in code:

```
var exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation: Int32 {
    let exifOrientation: DeviceOrientation
    enum DeviceOrientation: Int32 {
        case top0ColLeft = 1
        case top0ColRight = 2
        case bottom0ColRight = 3
        case bottom0ColLeft = 4
        case left0ColTop = 5
        case right0ColTop = 6
        case right0ColBottom = 7
        case left0ColBottom = 8
    }
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        exifOrientation = .left0ColBottom
    case .landscapeLeft:
        exifOrientation = .top0ColLeft
    case .landscapeRight:
        exifOrientation = .bottom0ColRight
    default:
        exifOrientation = .right0ColTop
    }
    return exifOrientation.rawValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, CodeBender. Appreciate if you could point me to a location where I can find the full code. Best regards.

Comment: @AndreGuerra I posted the link. You can find it on "posted here:" in my answer.

Comment: o.O - My bad. Hadn't noticed it before. Thks.

Comment: Can you explain why is the default value returning the equivalent of a 6? I've looked it up on Apple's documentation and 6 corresponds to a CGImagePropertyOrientation.**right**. It doesn't make sense to enumerate 8 different DeviceOrientation and use only 4 of them right? Somehow I've applied this missing piece to my Face recognition demo and it worked, just can't explain why.

Comment: @AndreGuerra Venturing a guess that it is to handle mirrored images, but then is not accounted for in the switch below?

Comment: It still doesn't explain why a regular portrait orientation on the device returns an exif orientation of right0ColTop (equivalent to 6). It does cause the FaceRecognition to work, but the reason is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at "[Training a Create ML Model to Classify Flowers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/training_a_create_ml_model_to_classify_flowers)" from Apple. The related code should work for iOS 12.x.

I have used the code posted in this thread without realizing they are not (or no longer) correct. I detected this only when I started testing an image localization model which draws a bounding box as well as classification. So if you have the same trouble, you can try change the code.

I am going back to my classification model to see if the accuracy improves. My intended object has rotational invariance so I don't expect this to change much. But for all models that have a clear orientation, your accuracy may drop, if you don't do the orientation correctly.